# How can I filter incoming transactions for a given address?

Tags: ethereum, web3js

using Infura as my Ethereum node I have subscribed to the `pendingTransactions` item in the web socket.  I receive a transaction ID for **every** transaction that occurs.  in order to determine whether it is relevant to me, I must call the `getTransaction()` method

I'm therefore having to call that method 100,000 times, which makes me exceed the Infura quota

to be fair, I don't even want pending transactions.  I would prefer completed transactions, but the API doesn't seem to offer that

I have come across this article: https://medium.com/coinmonks/monitoring-an-ethereum-address-with-web3-js-970c0a3cf96d which seems to support the notion that Ethereum doesn't make this easy

can anyone recommend a better approach?

TIA, ekkis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe to any websocket channel that your node provider supports. However, most providers (including Infura) use either [go-ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/) or [openethereum](https://openethereum.org/) client software that by default only implement the four channels listed in the web3js docs: `pendingTransactions`, `newBlockHeaders`, `syncing`, and `logs`.

So in order to subscribe only to mined transactions to/from a specified address, you'll need to find a provider that implements a transactions channel with a filter (unlikely). Or to run your own node and extend its code with a custom implementation of the channel (technically possible, but it's not a small scope).

Workaround: Use an external service that collects all transactions, stores them in a searchable DB and allows their users to request filtered data. For example Etherscan has a limited free [endpoint](https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints/accounts#get-a-list-of-normal-transactions-by-address) for this case.

Comment: thank you.  that was comprehensive and authoritative.  really a sad state of affairs that after 10 years Ethereum still doesn't make the most basic of functionality available but have to resort to such shenanigans.  thanks again, I'll look into Etherscan

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using alchemy API

```
import requests
from websockets import connect
import async.io
alchemy_ws_url="wss://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/YOUR_ALCHEMY_API"
async def subscribe_to_pending_transactions():
    ws_url = alchemy_ws_url
    subscription_data = {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "id": 1,
        "method": "eth_subscribe",
        "params": ["alchemy_pendingTransactions", {
            "fromAddress":"0xbd2C6a28a156377bD75C363aD8f849c68922b4Dc" #The address you want to monitor be it from or to
            # "toAddress": "0x3fC91A3afd70395Cd496C647d5a6CC9D4B2b7FAD"
        }]
    }

async with websockets.connect(ws_url) as websocket:
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(subscription_data))

    while True:
        response = await websocket.recv()
        response_data = json.loads(response)
        if "params" in response_data and "result" in response_data["params"]:
            #transaction_data = response_data["params"]['result']['from']
            transaction_data = response_data["params"]
            print(transaction_data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(subscribe_to_pending_transactions())
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool that does exactly what you needed, you'll have to give the tool your node RPC(HTTP) address, block number to start indexing and it has a web interface for you to be uploading a list of addresses to be checking/watching for their incoming transactions (smart contract transactions excluded), you'll then get notified when you have an incoming transaction to one of the addresses, notification is sent to a webhook address that you provided.

https://github.com/ahmadbrainworks/fiddi

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](/help/deleted-answers).